# TensorFlow - predicting next word - loss function logit na target shape

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, seq, language-model

I'm trying to create a language model. I have `logit` and target of size: `[32, 312, 512]`

Where:

- `.shape[0]` is `batch_size`
- `.shape[1]` is `sequence_max_len`
- `.shape[2]` is `vocabulary size`

The question is - when I pass `logit` and `target` to the loss function as follows:

```
self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
                                          logits=self.logit, labels=self.y))
```

Does it compute appropriate loss for the current batch? Or should I reshape `logit` and `target` to express the following shape: `[32, 312*512]`?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The answer is: it's irrelevant**, since `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()` have `dim` argument:

```
dim: The class dimension. Defaulted to -1 which is the last dimension.
name: A name for the operation (optional).
```

Also inside `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()` you have this code:

```
# Make precise_logits and labels into matrices.
precise_logits = _flatten_outer_dims(precise_logits)
labels = _flatten_outer_dims(labels)
```

Answer (score 1):

The api documentation says about labels,

> labels: Each row labels[i] must be a valid probability distribution

If you are predicting each character at a time, you would have a probability distribution (probability of being each character sum up to 1) over your vocab size 512. Given that, your labels and unscaled logits of shape [32, 312, 512], you should reshape it into [32*312, 512] before calling the function. In this way each row of your labels have a valid probability distribution and your unscaled logits will be converted to prob distribution by the function itself and then loss will be calculated.

Comment: No, you don't need to - see my answer for more details.